How to manually name Azure Resource Group within .NET 9 Aspire?
Is there a way to define the Azure Resource Group name and other resources within .NET 9 Aspire to ensure that the naming is exactly as provided or follows a specific naming pattern when publishing to Azure?
I want to control the naming of my resources when deploying my .NET 9 Aspire application to Azure. I'm looking for a way to explicitly define the resource group name and other resource names or to provide a naming convention that Azure will follow during the deployment process.

Please add more details about the issue.

using public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Azure.Provisioning.Primitives.Provisionable> GetProvisionableResources (); any Get any resources represented by this object.Refer this doc for more details.

To manually control the naming of Azure resources in .NET 9 Aspire, you can follow these steps from the MSDOC, using the InfrastructureResolver pattern and customizing the configuration for your resource group.
builder.AddAzureCosmosDB("ecoDriverCosmosDb")
    .ConfigureInfrastructure(infrastructure =>
    {
        var cosmosAccount = infrastructure.GetProvisionableResources().OfType<CosmosDBAccount>().Single();
        cosmosAccount.Name = "ecoDriverCosmosDb";  
    });


Set the Azure Resource Group Name:
using Azure.Provisioning;
using Azure.Provisioning.Primitives;

var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<AzureProvisioningOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ResourceGroupName = "MyCustomResourceGroup"; 
});

builder.AddAzureCosmosDB("ecoDriverCosmosDb");




Here's how you can do it:
public sealed class FixedNameInfrastructureResolver(IConfiguration configuration) : InfrastructureResolver
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private const string UniqueNamePrefix = "<YourCompanyPrefix>";

    public FixedNameInfrastructureResolver(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public override void ResolveProperties(ProvisionableConstruct construct, ProvisioningBuildOptions options)
    {
        string resourceGroup = _configuration["Azure:ResourceGroup"] ?? throw new AppHostConfigurationException("Missing 'Azure:ResourceGroup' configuration");
        string environmentSuffix = resourceGroup.EndsWith("dev") ? "-dev" : string.Empty;

        switch (construct)
        {
            case CosmosDBAccount cosmosAccount:
                ConfigureCosmosDb(cosmosAccount, environmentSuffix);
                break;

            case StorageAccount storageAccount:
                storageAccount.Name = $"{UniqueNamePrefix}{storageAccount.BicepIdentifier.ToLowerInvariant()}{environmentSuffix.Replace("-", string.Empty)}";
                break;

            case CognitiveServicesAccount cognitiveServicesAccount:
                ConfigureOpenAi(cognitiveServicesAccount, environmentSuffix);
                break;

            case KeyVaultService keyVault when keyVault.BicepIdentifier == "secrets":
                keyVault.Name = $"kv-{UniqueNamePrefix}-{keyVault.BicepIdentifier.ToLowerInvariant()}{environmentSuffix}";
                break;

            case ApplicationInsightsComponent insightsComponent:
                insightsComponent.Name = $"{insightsComponent.BicepIdentifier.ToLowerInvariant()}{environmentSuffix}".Replace('_', '-');
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private static void ConfigureCosmosDb(CosmosDBAccount account, string? envSuffix)
    {
        string resourceName = $"{UniqueNamePrefix}-{account.BicepIdentifier}";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envSuffix))
        {
            resourceName = $"{resourceName}{envSuffix}";
        }

        account.Name = resourceName.ToLowerInvariant();
        account.DatabaseAccountOfferType = CosmosDBAccountOfferType.Standard;

        account.ConsistencyPolicy = new ConsistencyPolicy()
        {
            DefaultConsistencyLevel = DefaultConsistencyLevel.Session
        };

        account.Capabilities.Add(new BicepValue<CosmosDBAccountCapability>(new CosmosDBAccountCapability()
        {
            Name = "EnableServerless"
        }));
    }
    private static void ConfigureOpenAi(CognitiveServicesAccount account, string? envSuffix)
    {
        string resourceName = $"{UniqueNamePrefix}-{account.BicepIdentifier}";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envSuffix))
        {
            resourceName = $"{resourceName}{envSuffix}";
        }

        account.Name = resourceName;
        account.Location = new BicepValue<AzureLocation>(AzureLocation.SwedenCentral);
    }
}


In the example below, you can define an InfrastructureResolver globally:
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<AzureProvisioningOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ProvisioningBuildOptions.InfrastructureResolvers.Insert(0, new FixedNameInfrastructureResolver(configuration));
});

builder.AddAzureCosmosDB("ecoDriverCosmosDb")
       .ConfigureInfrastructure(infrastructure =>
       {
           var cosmosAccount = infrastructure.GetProvisionableResources().OfType<CosmosDBAccount>().Single();
           cosmosAccount.Name = "ecoDriverCosmosDb";
       });


For more details, refer to this git for  Azure Provisioning client library.


Refer to the MSDOC and this my SO for guidance on dockerizing and deploying a .NET Aspire project to Azure Container Apps.
